# How to use data from last query as argument for next call of the same query with RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm moving from plain redux thunks to RTK query and I've run into a problem. After first query, the response contains a field with a value (kinda token or cursor) and I need to use it as argument in the next fetch of the same query and so on. With plain thunks I just read the token value from the store with a selector and use it as an argument

Something like this, but of course it causes an error:

```
const { data } = useUsersQuery({
  someToken: data.someToken,
});
```

How can I achieve it?

**UPDATE**
I solved it with `useLazyQuery()`:

```
const [trigger, { data }] = useLazyUsersQuery();

trigger({
  someToken: data?.someToken,
});
```

It looks ugly, though

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `skipToken` or the `skip` option:

```
const { data } = useUsersQuery({
  someToken: firstResult.data.someToken,
}, {
  skip: !firstResult.isSuccess
});
```

or

```
const { data } = useUsersQuery(firstResult.isSuccess ? {
  someToken: firstResult.data.someToken,
} : skipToken);
```

Comment: how can I get firstResult variable?

Comment: `const firstResult = useSomeOtherQuery()`

Comment: it's the same query, someToken is from the first fetch and used for next fetches

Comment: Ah, your question initially sounded like multiple different dependent queries. That's a pretty unique use case you have there - the lazyQuery is probably a good solution.